# systemctl daemon reload without ssh to the node

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, kubernetes, systemctl

I am working on s3 storage and kubernetes technologies and I have a scenario where we need to do a `systemctl dameon-reload` after  the driver binary is copied. How can this be done from a privileged pod without doing ssh to the worker node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the code in front of me, but I had great success using [CoreOS/go-systemd](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/releases/tag/v15) and volume mounting `/var/lib/dbus` (IIRC) into a privileged container (as you already mentioned)

My use case was to do this in a DaemonSet, so *every* Node did it, but if you wish to target just one node, then `spec: nodeName:` of the [PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.8/#podspec-v1-core) would enable you to schedule on that one specific Node

I will try to remember to update this with a gist containing the tl;dr of the go binary

Comment: Thanks @Matthew L Daniel for the reply. I am going to give a try. We are using ubuntu machines.

Comment: apologies for the delay, I finally remembered to [post a gist](https://gist.github.com/mdaniel/235110889c16515e09615dde0ecc2717#file-main-go) of the go-binary I used to issue a `systemctl daemon-reload`, followed by `systemctl enable` of specific unit files; I can't swear it's perfect, but I did verify that it worked at least once :-)